# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.) for requests coming from an iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `sdk.js` file which essentially embeds an iframe.

The sdk.js is handled by my Rails app.

To get this to work, I added:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:sdk]

def sdk
  # render "sdk.js"
end
```

The SDK simply embed an iframe that has the `src` set to my app.
That iframe also has some JS on it that calls various methods on my app, one of them being `record_event`

I know I can by adding this to all my routes, but I wanted to better understand why it's happening. I got some tips from [AppSignal](https://www.appsignal.com/for/invalid_authenticity_token).

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

The JS that comes from the iFrame IS passing the authenticity token.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/l/XXXX/XXXX/record_event
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Length: 23326
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: __profilin=p%3Dt; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-Request-Id: bee64e2a-14cf-4c7d-b91e-5fe4d94057ff
X-Runtime: 0.120436
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000//l/iframe/r2g-digital/1GII-66I36?prospectId=1GII-66I36&page=embed
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token: ISIxKz9-xOQdpFMsjJbpD8iwk7VBo84FH3qr4lJfuFGzZMC3_kUI8VC-Hgt9Xmxa9PeF1_O0YjNNVp7EtbtU_g
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Therefore X-CSRF-TOKEN is present so I wouldn't expect this error.

How can I get rid of these errors without having to skip the verification of the authenticity token?

Comment: The big elefant in the room here is that the Rails CRSF protection is dependent on cookies and that sharing your cookies with  an iframe is problematic to say the least. You're actually comparing the token passed in the headers or parameters to a token thats stored in an encrypted cookie. https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-csrf-protection-in-rails-19fa0a42c0ef

Comment: Getting the Rails CSRF protection to work with a same domain iframe might be doable (until the browser vendors crack down further on iframes) but cross-domain is gonna be very tough nut to crack - especially as thats the very thing that its intended to prevent.

Comment: There are alternatives to the Rails approach which are stateless such as the [HMAC Token Pattern](https://www.nedmcclain.com/better-csrf-protection/) but I'm not aware of any actual implementations for Rails.